# How can I order html table with data from database?

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-table

I've got a question regarding a html table and data from a database.

I managed to create a html table, which fetches data from a mysql database. So far it works fine. I am using auto increment within the database.

Unfortunately the html table is going from up to down. So the first entry has ID 1, while the last entry has a higher number. I want to change that so that the entry with the higher ID is displayed on top.

Is there any possibility to do that without Javascript or buttons? I didn't found a solution yet.

Comment: "I have not very much programming skills" That much is obvious ;-) What's wrong with javascript?

Comment: @Strawberry. How would you suggest fixing it?

Comment: @JefréN. I'd probably use DESC, like you suggest - but it may be more appropriate to simply sort the PHP array, or the html output directly (with the javascript which the OP appears to fear)

Comment: @Strawberry. They could do it that way. However, if they can order it the way they want in their query--we both know that they can--It is probably the simplest, most understandable solution they can use. Would you not agree?

Comment: @Andreas: can you add your code that fetch data ? then it will be more easy to suggest a simple solution in your case.

Comment: @JefréN. Each re-order requires another trip to the database. This can be wasteful. Anyway, my point was that the OP is not bound to one particular method. There are options.

Comment: @Strawberry: Thanks for the clarification. :D

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback. Actually I would use javascript if I would have any idea of it. 

As you see I don't have a good understanding of code. So I missed that I actually have an SQL query within the php code. Solution described here workes perfect. Thank you all for your time! I'll do better next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ORDER BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html) change the list to start from higher number to the lower.

> The **ORDER BY** keyword is used to sort the result-set by one or more columns, it sorts the result-set in ascending by default if you want it in descending (your case) you can use the **DESC** keyword.

So update your SQL query as follow.

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME_TO_SORT DESC
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html

---

You can also use **PHP**'s **usort()** function to sort the result-set fetched from database.

Sample code to sort the array by specific column using **usort()**

```
usort($finalarray, function($a, $b) {
    return $finalarray['COLUMN_NAME_TO_SORT'] - $finalarray['COLUMN_NAME_TO_SORT'];
});
// Assuming $finalarray is a result-set from database and it's an array.
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

---

> **ORDER BY** in SQL directly is preferred and better option to sort the result by higher
>   ID to lower.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your detailed explanation. Highly appreciated! I found this part on mysql documentation before, but I didn't think that I have used  an SQL query in my code to fetch the data (which I did, of course). I'll do better next time.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do that in a MySQL statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

It's the last line you need to add. With `ORDER BY` you can set the order in which the `SELECT` results are presented. The order can be `DESC` (descending), or `ASC` (ascending). You can order on multiple columns, seperated by comma's, it will then first sort on the first column, then on the second, etc.

Comment: Do you mind telling them why this solution is correct, so that they know what is wrong next time?

Comment: @Jefré N.: I don't understand your question? Andreas didn't use any ordering, so I showing him how to order decending on ID. What he didn't do wasn't really wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I hope I didn't offend you. I was simply referring to the fact that he/she may not know what DESC/ASC are used for and what they mean. That is all I meant. :D

Comment: Yes, you're right, that could be the case. I didn't think of that. I added an explanation.

Comment: Thanks! Puppies are smiling. Would I be pushing your generosity too much to suggest a link? ... maybe?

Comment: Thank you a lot! I know my question was kind of stupid, so I really appreciate your time to get me solve my problem.